# how do I make a variable value show text in html?

Tags: javascript, html, text, show, var

I need to make a specific number (0 through 2) show certain text for a rock paper scissors game.

I haven't tried anything yet but I can't think of anything. If someone could please make a variable value activating lines of code in html to show on the website.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help] for more information on what makes an acceptable question. [Do some research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/4665) before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your value comes from backend (or somewhere), here's how you can use JavaScript to display it to HTML:

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="text"></h1>
</body>
<script>
  const TEXT = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
  const value = 0;
  document.getElementById('text').innerText = TEXT[value];
</script>
```

For example, if this is PHP, this number can be injected to the HTML:

```php
<body>
  <h1 id="text"></h1>
</body>
<script>
  const TEXT = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
  const value = <?php echo($value) ?>;
  document.getElementById('text').innerText = TEXT[value];
</script>
```